# Why lock is needed to implement a readonly int property?

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking

I'm new to threading and I came accross a custom thread pool implementation example in a [blog](http://ferruh.mavituna.com/net-multithreading-ve-basit-bir-threadpool-implementasyonu-oku/). I'm pasting just the necessary parts of the code:

```
Public Class ThreadPool

    Private CountLock As New Object
    Private _Count As Integer

    Public ReadOnly Property ThreadCount() As Integer
      Get
         SyncLock CountLock
           Return _Count
         End SyncLock
      End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Open()
      Interlocked.Increment(_Count)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Close()
      Interlocked.Decrement(_Count)
      ....
    End Sub

EndClass
```

My question is, why do we need a lock to implement the readonly ThreadCount property?

Comment: The code in the link is not even close to resembling a thread pool.

Comment: I think at the end I'll send this page's link to the author of the blog :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock will force a memory barrier, so that a stale value from the CPU cache isn't read if the last value written was written by a different CPU. The same could be done with `Thread.VolatileRead()` without locking.

Answer (score 2):

This code should be using [Interlocked.CompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583.aspx) to access the value in the property getter.  Set param3 (*comparand*) to something that you know cannot be seen in the variable, like `Int32.MinValue`, and then the function just returns the current value of `_count`.

If `Interlocked` operations are used for all accesses to the variable, the lock is redundant since all access via `Interlocked` class methods is atomic.

Comment: I think I missed something while learning about locks. Can you explain why lock would be necessary if he wasn't using Interlocked, but just a lock in Open/Close?

Comment: @davsan - Interlocked class uses platform-specific processor instructions to guarantee atomic behaviour when accessing variables of primitive type like `Int32` and `Int64`, or native pointers. If you can make sure all access to `_count` is via `Interlocked`, this will be the most efficient way to handle thread safety on `_count`. Any higher level lock will be more costly. Otherwise, get rid of the `Interlocked` usage and use `lock(_count)` everywhere - it does not make sense to mix and match.

Comment: @Steve - OK, I understood what you've explained. I think what I miss is here: afaik, lock (CountLock) { return _count;} limits that only one thread can execute the {return _count} section at one time, so what would be the disadvantage if multiple threads execute this same section at the same time? I think I'm unaware of read safety issues?

Comment: @davsan - this might work so long as _count is not used anywhere else.  However I am not sure how reliable it is to mix Interlocked operations (which lock at the machine level) with non-interlocked (eg. protected using managed code lock()).  I am not sure if an atomic read is guaranteed if you happen to get inside the managed code lock() while another thread is updating the underlying memory via `Interlocked.Decrement` or `Interlocked.Increment`.  I would not mix these data protection types unless you are sure.

Comment: @davsan - see also my question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855904/interlocked-class-mixed-with-lock

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why the author choose to use a lock in one part of the class while utilizing lock-free techniques in other parts. However, I can make an assumption that the author did it to create an explicit memory barrier on the read of the `Interger`. VB does not contain the equivalent of C#'s `volatile` keyword so that leaves just 4 other common methods for making the read safe. I have listed these in the order that I would choose for this *specific scenario*.

- Interlocked.CompareExchange
- Thread.VolatileRead
- Thread.MemoryBarrier
- SyncLock

The memory barrier is required to prevent the VB or JIT compilers from moving instructions around. The most likely optimization in the absence of a memory barrier is to lift the read outside of a loop. Consider this realistic use of the `ThreadCount` property.

```
Sub LoggingThread()
  Do While True
    Trace.WriteLine(ThreadPool.ThreadCount)
  Loop
End Sub
```

In this example the CLR would likely inline `ThreadCount` and then potentially "lift" the read of `_Count` and cache it in a CPU register before the loop begins. The effect would be that the same value would always be displayed.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>In reality the `Trace.WriteLine` call itself generates a memory barrier that would cause the code to be safe by accident. The example was intended as a simple illustration of what could happen.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense, as there is no lock where you modify the property. Maybe the code was not using Interlocked operations before, and was using SyncLock even in Open / Close? In such case SyncLock would be really needed in the read access as well.

Comment: Are you sure it makes no sense? Adding locks adds a memory barrier which will prevent instruction reordering, might make a difference.

Comment: Prevent instruction ordering on a property like ThreadCount? I don't think so - it would be purely an informational/debugging property. Any real logic would be done with _Count.

Comment: @Lasse a lone read of an `int` is atomic in .NET. Re-ordering would only be a problem if the caller is also calling other members and there is enough inlining going on: it could be but would imply tight coupling that probably means the locking should be in the caller.

Comment: Could be, all I wanted to point out that the issue might not be as clear-cut as indicated. I sure don't know the answer.

Comment: @Richard, re-ordering wouldn't be a problem, but CPU cache could.