# Can Interlocked class safely be mixed with lock()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is an atomic read guaranteed when you mix Interlocked operations with lock() (and other higher-level locks)?

I am interested in general behaviour when mixing locking mechanisms like this, and any differences between Int32 and Int64.

```
private Int64 count;
private object _myLock;

public Int64 Count 
{
  get 
  {
    lock(_myLock)
    {
      return count;
    }
  }
}

public void Increment
{
  Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
}
```

Comment: Never lock on `this`, the lock will conflict with one outside the class locking on the object. Only ever lock on private reference-type members. If you don't have an appropriate private reference-type member of the correct type vis-a-vis static or instance then have `private object _myLock;` or `private static object _myStaticLock;` just for that purpose.

Comment: I still have the feeling you may have bigger fish to fry than covered in this question. I'm happy with my answer as far as this question goes, but it doesn't deal with matters of thread A doing something on the basis of count while thread B changes the count, because whether that's an issue, and what to do about it if it is, depends on more than you give here.

Comment: @Jon - I think the basic point is made that mixing these metaphors is a minefield. Your note on usage of the locked value is certainly worth extra credit but there is no '+2' button. I really asked this question to clarify my uncertainty an answer of my own elsewhere today.

Comment: It is a minefield, though sometimes necessary, as I proved with the error (now fixed) in my answer below in forgetting about CPU caches (actually, IIRC it won't make any difference on an x86 architecture, but that's not something you should depend upon).

Comment: @Steve: I was wondering if the true spirit of your question would be better expressed if your example used an `Int64` instead of `Int32`. There is an `Interlocked.Increment` overload for 64 bit fields.

Comment: Ah! Now I have to change my answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note: This answer (including the two edits already) was given before the question was changed to have a long `count`. For the current question instead of `Thread.VolatileRead` I would use `Interlocked.Read`, which also has volatile semantics and would also deal with the 64-bit read issue discussed here and introduced into the question**

An atomic read is guaranteed without locking, because reads of properly-aligned values of 32-bit or less,  which your `count` is, are guaranteed to be atomic.

This differs from a 64-bit value where if it started at -1, and was read while another thread was incrementing it, could result in the value read being -1 (happened before increment), 0 (happened after increment) or either of 4294967295 or -4294967296 (32 bits written to 0, other 32bits awaiting write).

The atomic increment of `Interlocked.Increment` means that the whole increment operation is atomic. Consider that increment is conceptually:

1. Read the value.
2. Add one to the value.
3. Write the value.

Then if `x` is 54 and one thread tries to increment it while another tries to set it to 67, the two correct possible values are 67 (increment happens first, then is written over) or 68 (assignment happens first, then is incremented) but non-atomic increment can result in 55 (increment reads, assignment of 67 happens, increment writes).

A more common real case is `x` is 54 and one thread increments and another decrements. Here the only valid result is 54 (one up, then one down, or vice-versa), but if not atomic then possible results are 53, 54 and 55.

If you just want a count that is incremented atomically, the correct code is:

```
private int count;

public int Count 
{
  get 
  {
    return Thread.VolatileRead(byref count);
  }
}

public void Increment
{
  Interlocked.Increment(count);
}
```

If however you want to act upon that count, then it will need stronger locking. This is because the thread using the count can become out of date before its operation is finished. In this case you need to lock on everything that cares about the count and everything that changes it. Just how this need be done (and whether its even important to do at all) depends on more matters of your use-case than can be inferred from your question.

Edit: Oh, you may want to lock simply to force a memory barrier. You may also want to change `Count`'s implementation to `return Thread.VolatileRead(ref count);` to make sure CPU caches are flushed if you are going to remove the lock. It depends on how important cache staleness is in this case. (Another alternative is to make `count` volatile, as then all reads and writes will be volatile. Note that this isn't needed for the `Interlocked` operations as they are always volatile.)

Edit 2: Indeed, you're so likely to want this volatile read, that I'm changing the answer above. It **is** possible you won't care about what it offers, but much less likely.

Comment: Shouldn't count be declared volatile in this case? Otherwise you would end up with register cashing issues, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Martin. GMTA, was adding that as you commented. Again though, just what we want will depend on a few things. VolatileRead will serve what's in the question, but maybe `volatile` (as per your suggestion) would be better once other operations are added. It's worth adding for completeness that the `Interlocked` API has the correct memory barriers that volatility isn't needed with them (even says so in the documentation of the warning you get when you call them byref on a volatile field).

Comment: And kudos to the person asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853678/why-lock-is-needed-to-implement-a-readonly-int-property/ since it was in thinking of my answer to that, that I realised it applied here too.

Answer (score 3):

The argument provided to the lock keyword must be an object based on a reference type. In your code, this is value type, this possibly means boxing, which makes lock statement useless.

Interlocked operation is atomic relatively to another Interlocked operation running in another thread, and applied to the same variable. There is no thread safety, if one thread uses Interlocked operation, and another changes the same variable by using another synchronization algorithm, or without synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

> Is an atomic read guaranteed when you mix Interlocked operations with lock() (and other higher-level locks)?

An atomic read *of int* is *always* guaranteed regardless of locking of any kind. The C# specification states that reads of ints are *always* atomic.

I think that your actual question is different than the one you asked. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I intended to ask a more general question about mixing metaphors, edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You can NOT safely mix `lock` with `Interlock`. Example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UT5umn):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        object lockObj = new object ();
        var IncrementValue = 0;
        Parallel.For(0, 10000, x =>
        {
            //Incrementing the value
            if (x % 2 == 0)
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    IncrementValue++;
                }
            }
            else
                Interlocked.Increment(ref IncrementValue);
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Expected Result: 10000");
        Console.WriteLine("Actual Result: " + IncrementValue);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Expected Result: 10000
Actual Result: 9997
```

If you change both incrementing to `lock` or both to `Interlock` it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no.  The `lock` and `Interlocked` don't have anything to do with each other and they do not work together in the manner you are suggesting.

Also, not sure what is going on with your code.  It does not compile.  You can't lock on a value type.  Also, `Increment()` takes a `ref` argument.

Comment: Yeah, that will at least compile now. But for sure, these two types of locks will not sync with each other.  Also, you should never lock on this, but that is a totally different discussion.

Comment: And now that I think about it, you don't need the lock on the property at all. Returning an int is an atomic operation. If this is all you have, you can remove the lock (this) and you will not have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't lock on value types, like int.

When you lock on a value type, it gets boxed into an object first. The problem is that it will be boxed every time and every time it will be a different "box". You will be locking on a different object every time, rendering the lock block useless.

That problem aside, let's say you you lock on a reference type, and you use the Interlocked class on another thread. There will be no synchronization between the threads. When you want synchronization you *must* use the same mechanism on both threads.